# How do i sum data-price value from multiple checkboxes to exsiting function?

Tags: jquery, function, checkbox, sum

I am trying to add multiple optional checkboxes into my html form, so that if selected, the checkbox's data-price value will be added to the sum.

Problem is that I can only get the first selected checbox to add to the other input types, and not both of them.
Any help would be really great.

```
<body>

<form  id="form1">

<div id=go>
     <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="one" class="abc" data-price="1600">Live Band</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="two" class="abc" data-price="400">DJ</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="three" class="abc" data-price="500">Acoustic</label>
</div>


                         
                         
      <div id="example" class="container">  
            
            
           
          
            <select id="place">
                <option value="">pick</option>
                <option value="a" data-price="100" >a</option>
                <option value="b" data-price="200">b</option>
                <option value="c" data-price="300">c</option>
            </select>   
                           
      

            </div>      
            
            <div id="checker">
            <input type="checkbox" name="add-ons" id="add-dj" data-price="750">
            <input type="checkbox" name="add-ons" id="add-acoustic-wedding-music" data-price="450">
            </div>
</form>
            
        
        <div id="result" class="container"></div>
```

```
<script>  $(document).ready(function(){
             function validate() {
    var sum = 0;
    sum += +$('#go input:checked').data('price') || 0;
    sum += +$('#place option:selected').data('price') || 0;
    sum += +$('#checker input:checked').data('price') || 0;

    $('#result').html(sum === 0 ? '' : sum + '$');
  }
  validate();

  $('#go input, #place, #checker input').on('change', function() {
    validate();
        });
         
    });
        </script>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through `checked` checkboxes using each loop and then you can use `$(this).data('price')` and add same to `sum`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function validate() {
    var sum = 0;
    sum += +$('#go input:checked').data('price') || 0;
    sum += +$('#place option:selected').data('price') || 0;
    //loop through checked checkbox
    $('#checker input:checked').each(function() {
      sum += +$(this).data('price') //get dataprice add in sum
    })


    $('#result').html(sum === 0 ? '' : sum + '$');
  }
  validate();

  $('#go input, #place, #checker input').on('change', function() {
    validate();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">

  <div id=go>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="one" class="abc" data-price="1600">Live Band</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="two" class="abc" data-price="400">DJ</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="three" class="abc" data-price="500">Acoustic</label>
  </div>




  <div id="example" class="container">




    <select id="place">
      <option value="">pick</option>
      <option value="a" data-price="100">a</option>
      <option value="b" data-price="200">b</option>
      <option value="c" data-price="300">c</option>
    </select>



  </div>

  <div id="checker">
    <input type="checkbox" name="add-ons" id="add-dj" data-price="750">
    <input type="checkbox" name="add-ons" id="add-acoustic-wedding-music" data-price="450">
  </div>
</form>


<div id="result" class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Happy to help ..: ) You can accept this answer by clicking on that tick .